# how can i read variable to other page by post

Tags: php

i have link like this

```
<a href="PrintSingleCashier.php?id=<?=$objResult["cashiers_CashierID"]; ?>" target="_new"><img src="../images/print.png"></a>
```

and i wont to print variable `id` to other pages called `PrintSingleCashier.php`, i will insert id on link same this `PrintSingleCashier.php?id=<?=$objResult["cashiers_CashierID"]; ?>`.

but when go to this page `PrintSingleCashier.php` i cannot read `id`.

why !!

i read it like `$_GET["id"];` but i need read it like `$_POST["id"];`

Comment: why do you need it to be in $_POST, what's wrong with $_GET ?

Comment: What is the PHP version you are on?

Comment: What about storing $_POST['id'] in $_SESSION until you get the value to the other page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't get a $_POST variable trought a link, limited to use $_GET

This is NOT adviced, but anyway, if you must keep it being a $_POST variable to be compatible with previous code or something like that, just do a plain

```
$_POST["id"] = $_GET["id"]
```

at the very beginning of your "PrintSingleCashier.php"

Comment: I almost upvoted this until I got to the part where you told OP (and other readers) to do `$_POST["id"] = $_GET["id"]`. Even with the "not adviced" notice it is a terrible idea :(

Comment: I know, i even have the temptation to downvote myself, don't worry... just trying to give him a quick fix, a more complete/proper answer should include a whole article about superglobals and such... :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its because of `<?=`

Try this out

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"PrintSingleCashier.php?id=".$objResult["cashiers_CashierID"]."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"../images/print.png\"></a>";
?>
```

In page `PrintSingleCashier.php` read `id` as follows

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Ensure array `$objResult["cashiers_CashierID"]` has a value.

Good programming practice is that avoid using shortcut tags for PHP.

Comment: Even though it feels like this is not the real case, thumbs up for the best practice!